# How to find the largest size of training set that classifier allows?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree, cross-validation

I am new in Python and Machine Learning. I got the dataset which includes 581012 records and 54 column. I am trying to split the data 80 20. 80% for the training and 20% for testing. I use the GridSearchCV to do cross validation and find the best parameter. Since the data too large, I execute the application more than one days, but cannot get the results. I consider there any way to know what the maximum size of the training set that classifier allows is? Below is me execution code

```
parameters = {'max_depth' :range(1,21)}
print parameters 
clf = GridSearchCV(tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(), parameters, cv=10, n_jobs=-1)
clf.fit(X,y)

tree_model = clf.best_estimator_
import pickle
s = pickle.dumps(tree_model)
print(clf.best_score_, clf.best_params_)
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to prune your database before the training. You can also try WEKA tool .
http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/documentation.html